# Rails: Template Error "dynamic constant assignment"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, partial

In my view I render a partial.

The name of the partial is constructed by the name of a product page.

```
<%= render :partial => "product_pages/" + selected.headline %>
```

In the test case the headline is "electronics".

So I also tried:

```
<%= render :partial => "product_pages/electronics"
```

For testing the partial view looks like this:

```
<p>Test</p>
```

Now I get this error I do not understand:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/var/www/*****/app/views/product_pages/_Elektro
nik.html.erb:1: dynamic constant assignment
...r = @output_buffer;Elektronik = local_assigns[:Elektronik];;...
...                               ^):
    1: <p>Test</p>
  app/views/pages/_content.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_pages__content_html_erb__4
0580468132849538_266915680_1201196437383914942'
  app/views/pages/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb__43007964
38685262523_267219620_562910368159856764'
```

Comment: Is Elektronik mentioned anywhere in your view?

Comment: See also [dynamic constant assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `downcase` your headline:

```
selected.headline.downcase
```

This is because you're going to be rendering a partial like this: `product_pages/Elektronik`, and when you call `render :partial` it'll attempt to define a local variable that has the same name as the partial, which is why you're getting this error: the code *isn't* defining a local variable but is actually defining a constant.

If you `downcase` it, it will define a local variable rather than this constant.

Comment: of course! I was just not clever enough to see it in the error log.