# Using local constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Other than convention, is there any reason to use or not to use local constants in ruby blocks or methods?

For example:

```
get '/documents/:id' do
  Doc_id = params[:id]
  ...
  ...
end
```

versus

```
get '/documents/:id' do
  doc_id = params[:id]
  ...
  ...
end
```

Inside a block it seems to work, but in a method you get an error:

```
   def foo(bar)
      Foo = bar
      puts Foo.inspect
   end
   => SyntaxError: (irb):11: dynamic constant assignment
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic constant assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing is that in the method case you actually will alter the constant in every call to the method. You can initialize that kind of constants only once. This counts also for blocks. see here:

```
m = [1, 2]
m.each do |t|
    DOC_id = 123
    DOC_id = 12
end
```

Then you will get the following error:

```
(irb):12: warning: already initialized constant DOC_id
(irb):11: warning: already initialized constant DOC_id
(irb):12: warning: already initialized constant DOC_id
```

Proving that you can not reassign constants, even in blocks.

Comment: A warning shows that you can reassign, but Matz in one of his books says it a wrong way to code in Ruby