# Rails validate date "older than 17"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have three select fields in my view:

```
<%= select("policyholderdetail", "dob_day", days_options, {:prompt => "#{t :day}"}) %>
<%= select("policyholderdetail", "dob_month", months_options, {:prompt => "#{t :month}"}) %>
<%= select("policyholderdetail", "dob_year", dob_years_options, {:prompt => "#{t :year}"}) %>
```

Where the values for `:dob_day` range from 01-31, `:dob_month` from 01-12 and `dob_year` from 1912-2012 (last 100 years)

I would like to validate that someone's date of birth from this is at least 17 years ago, i.e. the person is at least 17 years old. How can I do this in my rails model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to make sure that you're saving only one DateTime to represent all three fields.

```
DateOfBirth = Time.parse ("#{ dob_year + dob_month + dob_day } " )
```

Then you just work against that date :

```
validates :is_seventeen?

def is_seventeen?
   DateOfBirth = Time.parse ("#{ dob_year + dob_month + dob_day } " )
   DateOfBirth > Time.now - 17.years ? true : false
end
```

**Tip..**

Outside of the specific answer, I would recommend that your DateOfBirth field is just one field and that those three selects represent one column in your table.

Comment: You can just stick the second part in your model. You will have to make sure you line up your params appropriately with `dob_year` `dob_month` and `dob_day`.

Comment: error: dynamic constant assignment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment

Comment: Paste what it is your code looks like in your question. Include your form, and controller action for `def create`.