# Defining a Struct during initialize

Tags: ruby

I have a class that reads a dynamic CSV file, and would like to create a struct based on the headers of the CSV.

It goes like this in pseudo-code:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(csvfile)
    @csv = CSV.open(csvfile, options.....)
    .....
    headers = @csv.headers  # => [:line, :error, :user, ........]   <==this is dynamic
    RECORD = Struct.new(headers)
    load_data
  end

  def load_data
    @records = []
    @csv.each do |r|
      @records << RECORD.new(r.fields)
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is that a constant can not (should not) be dynamically defined. So, what should be the proper way to address this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic constant assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment)

Comment: Not a dup actually. The issue is with the proper use of struct and not with the constant.

Comment: "The issue is that a constant can not (should not) be dynamically defined. So, what should be the proper way to address this?"

Comment: Regardless of whether you are talking about a Struct, a Hash, or a String, you can't dynamically assign to a constant. The important part of this question asks how to address the fact that a constant can not be dynamically defined, which is why I see it as a duplicate. Well, that's *my* reasoning anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use a constant. Use an instance variable.

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(csvfile)
    @csv = CSV.open(csvfile, options...)
    ...
    headers = @csv.headers
    @record = Struct.new(headers)
    load_data
  end
  def load_data
    @records = []
    @csv.each do |r|
      @records << @record.new(r.fields)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: OK, perfect, I've should have specified I knew that.
The issue here is that I WANT it to be a constant, which will be initialized just once. Said that, what I would like is a constant that can be initialized dynamically upon initialization.

Answer (score 0):

[@sawa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799784/2767755) answer is correct. I will add something more here.

*Constants* are used to store values which DO NOT change. If you change a constant in your program it is probably a *bug*. Ruby is trying to be helpful and say "Hold on! I think something strange is going on here. You said you wanted this to be a constant but now it's being changed!"

In Ruby, you are never allowed to put a constant assignment, inside a method definitions due to the reason as I just said above. If you try to do *constant assignment* inside a method, you will get *Syntax Error*. As per your need, you can use any variables, but not constant variables, inside a method.

If you do

```
Y = 1
#then
Y = 2
# warning: already initialized constant Y
# warning: previous definition of Y was here
```

But if you try,

```
def meth arg
  C = arg
end
# then 
# SyntaxError: dynamic constant assignment
# C = arg
#   ^
```