# Taking basic C# project and converting it to Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby

I'm taking an online class on Object-Oriented Programming. The languages that we are "required" to use (in other words the languages our instructor knows), are C++/C#/Java. I have nothing against that, I've done a tiny bit with C# before, but then I discovered Ruby and I vastly enjoy it.

For a recent project we were suppose to do this;

> Write a program called BasicClassObject using the DBPM format that will     define the following features listed below. 
>   Use any language (C++, C# or Java) to create the BasicClassObject class.
>
> Create a class name BasicClassObject.
>      Create one overloaded constructor that takes a string as a parameter.
>      Create one  attributes called type as a string data type (text). 
>      Create a setter (mutator) for the type attribute. Create a getter (accessor) for the type attribute. 
>      Create one other method called basicMethod that displays text and instantiate.
>
> OUTPUT
>
> Created Object:Global
>
> Created Object:Local A
>
> Method Scope Begins
>
> Created Object:Local B
>
> Method Scope Ends

Nice and easy:

```
class BasicClassObject
{
    private string type, someType;
    public BasicClassObject(string type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Created Object: {type}");
    }

    private string typeType
    {
        get
        {
            return someType;
        }
        set
        {
            someType = value;
        }
    }

    public void basicMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method Scope Begins");
        BasicClassObject LocalObject = new BasicClassObject("Local B");
        Console.WriteLine("Method Scope Ends\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BasicClassObject GlobalObject = new BasicClassObject("Global");
        BasicClassObject LocalObject = new BasicClassObject("Local A");
        LocalObject.basicMethod();

    }
}
```

Don't ask about what the `get` and `set`are in the class. For some reason that's how the instructor has always wanted us to do it (I have no idea why since those are usually outside of the class, and haven't really gotten a clear answer as to why either).

Anyhow, why not try it in Ruby? ([I used this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment#6712438) to fix an issue I ran into when using Netbeans to fix little errors)

```
 class BasicClassObject
   class << self
      attr_accessor :type, :localconstant
   end
   def basicmethod
       self.class.type = "Created Object: "
       self.class.localconstant = "Local B"
       puts "Method Scope Begins\n"
       sleep 0.5
       puts type + localconstant
       sleep 0.5
   end
 end

puts BasicClassObject.basicmethod

LocalObject = BasicClassObject.new("Local A")

puts LocalObject.basicmethod
```

**EDIT:** Did I create the Ruby code to be fairly similar to the C# code? I don't get any errors with Netbeans, and I can't exactly debug it because for whatever reason Netbeans can't install the fast debugger and the slow one takes ages. The only issue I can see is not being able to set the variable `localconstant` outside of the class.

I do know it's a little difficult to figure out the instructions. This is honestly seems like the far most complicated way of going about creating an object.

Comment: "did I properly convert the program from C# to Ruby?" – This question is way too broad for [so], but the short answer is: no. In fact, there is almost no relationship at all between the two programs, they don't even remotely do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the question is did I properly convert the program from C# to Ruby?

No. In fact, there is almost no relationship at all between the two programs, they don't even remotely do the same thing. Plus, the Ruby program doesn't even work, it raises a `NoMethodError` exception:

> ```
> in `<main>': undefined method `basicmethod' for BasicClassObject:Class (NoMethodError)
> ```

Let's first clean up your C♯ version a bit to make it easier to read:

```csharp
using static System.Console;

class BasicClassObject
{
    public BasicClassObject(string type) => WriteLine($"Created Object: {type}");

    string type { get; set; }

    void basicMethod()
    {
        WriteLine("Method Scope Begins");
        new BasicClassObject("Local B");
        WriteLine("Method Scope Ends");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new BasicClassObject("Global");
        new BasicClassObject("Local A").basicMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, let's translate it to Ruby:

```ruby
class BasicClassObject
  attr_accessor :type

  def initialize(type) puts "Created Object: #{type}" end

  def basic_method
    puts "Method Scope Begins"
    BasicClassObject.new("Local B")
    puts "Method Scope Ends"
  end
end

BasicClassObject.new("Global")
BasicClassObject.new("Local A").basic_method
```

Comment: That makes more sense from a Ruby stand point. I now see I was trying too hard to almost exactly replicate what the C# code was doing, which is pointless since they're very different languages. No more writing code at 1AM for me.

Comment: Actually, your Ruby code doesn't even remotely replicate the C♯ code. In your C♯ code, there is one field `type`, in your Ruby code, there are two fields `type` and `localconstant` (which doesn't even appear anywhere in the C♯ code). In your C♯ code, you call `basicMethod` *once* on a newly-created *instance* of `BasicClassObject`, in your Ruby code, you call it *twice*, first on the class `BasicClassObject` *itself*. In the C♯ code, you define a constructor, in the Ruby code, you do *not* define an initializer. …

Comment: … In the C♯ code, you *print* some strings to the console, in the Ruby code, you assign those same strings to fields. In the Ruby code, you have some `sleep`s that do not appear in the C♯ code. The two really are completely different.

Comment: Again, I think I'll trying doing this type of personal practice at a time of day when I'm fully awake.