# How do I pass in code to functions?

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code that executes a series of commands and keep retrying until it reaches MAX_RETRIES. I don't want to repeat this over and over again for different commands. Is there an elegant way of doing so?

```
    retries = 0
    ex = true
    MAX_RETRIES = 10

    while(retries <= MAX_RETRIES and ex)
       begin
          #MY CODE HERE
          ex = false
        rescue
           ex = true
        end
        retries = retries + 1

    end
```

Something like this?

```
execute_with_retries do
  #CODE HERE
end

execute_with_retries do
  #DIFFERENT CODE HERE
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function and execute the block

```
def execute_with_retries
  retries = 0
  ex = true
  max_retries = 10

  while(retries <= max_retries and ex)
    begin
      yield
      ex = false
    rescue
      ex = true
    end
    retries = retries + 1
  end
end

execute_with_retries { puts "hello" }
execute_with_retries { puts 1/0 }
```

I renamed one of your variable and you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment) why.
It's also worth noting that something like this exists in Ruby and you can read about it [here](http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-to-try-again-when-exceptions-happen-in-ruby/).

Comment: Can u give me an example on how I would call this?

Comment: `execute_with_retries { puts "hello" }` or `execute_with_retries { puts 1/0 }`. Add a print statement with the number of tries at the end of your method

Answer (score 0):

```
MAX_RETRIES = 10

def execute_with_retries(meth)
    retries = 0
    ex = true
    while(retries <= MAX_RETRIES and ex)
      begin
        public_send(meth)
        ex = false
      rescue
        ex = true
      end
      retries = retries + 1
    end
    retries
end

require 'time.h'

def meth
  sleep(1)
  puts "Time.now in m = #{Time.now}"
  puts Time.now - @start < 5 ? "cat"/9 : "dog"
end

@start = Time.now
  #=> 2017-12-30 13:39:20 -0800
execute_with_retries(:meth)

Time.now in m = 2017-12-30 13:39:21 -0800
Time.now in m = 2017-12-30 13:39:22 -0800
Time.now in m = 2017-12-30 13:39:23 -0800
Time.now in m = 2017-12-30 13:39:24 -0800
Time.now in m = 2017-12-30 13:39:25 -0800
"dog"
  #=> 5
```