# I want to have a variable increment when I click the link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
.col-md-2.col-sm-12.arrow_container{:style => "text-align:right;"}
  - if Date > 0
    = link_to movies_path(Date -= 1) do
      %i.fa.fa-caret-left
  - else
    %i.fa.fa-caret-left

/my display date code/

.col-md-2.col-sm-12.arrow_container{:style => "text=align:left;"}
  = link_to movies_path(Date += 1) do
    %i.fa.fa-caret-right
```

here's my code I want this button to be disabled when I am on the current date. When I hit the right arrow. I want the variable Date to increment by 1 and then the left arrow will be available.  Right now I am getting an error for.

```
dynamic constant assignment ... = link_to movies_path(Date -= 1) do
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic constant assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment)

Comment: I changed the variable name and still same error

Comment: `Date` is a ruby class, you cannot use it as a counter variable.

Comment: how do I make it a variable and not a class

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put the increment or decrement in the if condition statement 

`- if date > 0 && date -= 1
    = link_to movies_path(date) do`

By the way, the variable should better be lower case.