# Why there is an error in the code dynamic constant assignment Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
# Global constants

X = "X"             # cross
O = "O"             # toe
EMPTY = ""          # empty board
TIE = "DRAW"        # draw state
NUMBER_SQUARES = 9  # number of fields on the board
```

Creates a new game board - 
a list of nine elements equal to `EMPTY` and returns it

```
def new_playing_board
    create_board = Array.new(NUMBER_SQUARES) { EMPTY }
end

board = new_playing_board
```

The function takes the board and returns the winner of the game.
Four possible values ​​can be returned: `"X"`, `"O"` - computer or human, 
`TIE` - if all fields are completed, 
`nil` - one of the fields is empty and the winner is not defined

```
def win_play(board)

    WAYS_TO_WIN = [    # backtrace error: dynamic constant assignment WAYS_TO_WIN = [ rb:136
                [0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8],
                [0, 3, 6],
                [1, 4, 7],
                [2, 5, 8],
                [0, 4, 8],
                [2, 4, 6]
                ]


    WAYS_TO_WIN.each do |row|
        if (board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] && board[row[0]] == board[row[2]]) != EMPTY
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
        end

        unless board.include?(EMPTY)
            return TIE
        end
    end

    return nil 

end


win_play(board)
```

backtrace: dynamic constant assignment WAYS_TO_WIN = [ rb:136

Comment: What is the error you're referring to? What is the backtrace?

Comment: fixed error shown

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6712298/5025116) for further information.

Comment: Must be put, just points ran out for today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reassign `WAYS_TO_WIN` every time `win_play` is called

```
def win_play(board)

    WAYS_TO_WIN =
```

define `WAYS_TO_WIN` outside of the method, e.g. with all the other constants

```
NUMBER_SQUARES = 9  # number of fields on the board
WAYS_TO_WIN = ...
```