# Assigning a variable the length of a string or array causes a "dynamic constant assignment" error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, string-length

I started working with Ruby today and looked up the appropriate syntax for basic operations. Apparently I wasn't careful enough because the lines calling length below throw the error "dynamic constant assignment". There may be even more mistakes waiting to be uncovered after this is fixed, but for now I will only focus on this error.

```
def isPalindrome(n)
    m = n.to_s;
    L = m.length; <-- error
    for i in 0..L/2
        if(m[i] != m[L-1-i])
            return false;
        end
    end
    return true;
end

def nthmax(n, a)
    L = a.length; <-- error
    if(n > L)
        return nil;
    end
    a.sort;
    return a[L-n];
end
```

Searching the error message leads to posts about how the error is thrown when someone tries to assign a constant a value that isn't actually constant. The question given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712298/dynamic-constant-assignment) is not relevant because I'm not trying to make L a constant (this info was added to clarify that the question, at the time I asked it, was not a duplicate, nor is it a duplicate now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if the 1st letter of a variable is capitalized, it's treated as a constant. "L" should be changed to "l".

Answer (score 0):

You stumbled over an unusual design aspect in Ruby language. Ruby does not have `constants`, but it calls identifiers that start with upper case latters as *constants*. You are allowed to modify them, but get a warning (**not** an error!) if you do this, as it happed in your assignment to `L`. If you **really** want to modify a constant without warning, you can do it with

```
# Don't do this unless you really have to!!!!
self.class.send(:remove_const, :L) # Make it disappear
L = new_value # Recreate it
```

It is considered bad practice (as you can already guess from the fact that `remove_const` is now a private method), and you do these tricks mostly if you go into Ruby meta-programming. In your case, I see no reason why you can't use a normal local variable instead.

Comment: Your workaround was not helpful because I do not want to use constants. I wanted the program to recognize length as a variable, hence renaming L to l.

Comment: It was not meant as a _workaround_ : As I said, you **usually** never want to modify "constants", though they were cases where it could make sense, and **for this case only**, I showed how to do it. For your concrete program, I suggested to use a local variable instead, which is apparently what you did anyway, since variables starting with a lower case letter, are local. In other situations, an instance- or class variable (`@l`, respectively  `@@l`) could also be advisable, but not necessary here.