# How can I make my simple Ruby Class more concise, it seems cumbersome?

Tags: ruby

Can I somehow use Struct or OpenStruct to make my class more concise?

```
class RecipientScorer::ScoreResult

  attr_accessor :id, :score_data, :total_score, :percent_match

  def initialize(id, score_data, total_score, percent_match)
    @id = id
    @score_data = score_data
    @total_score = total_score
    @percent_match = percent_match
  end

end
```

Comment: Did you try `RecipientScorer::ScoreResult = Struct.new(:id, :score_data, :total_score, :percent_match)`?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763016/how-to-cleanly-initialize-attributes-in-ruby-with-new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains the answer - use [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html):

```
RecipientScorer::ScoreResult = Struct.new(
  :id,
  :score_data,
  :total_score,
  :percent_match
)
```